# Confusion on the mathematical aspect of the Translation operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum

I know that the Translation operator shifts particles/fields in a direction and can be written as $$\hat{T}(x) = e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{p}x}.$$
What confuses me is that when we rewrite $\hat{p} = \frac{h}{i}\nabla$ we obtain:

$$\hat{T}(x) = e^{-\nabla x} = e^{-1} ~??$$
Which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a better idea to write the operator that shifts wavefunctions by an amount $\lambda$ to be $\hat T(\lambda) =e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat p \lambda}$.

The derivative in $\hat p$ is with respect to the spatial coordinate of a wavefunction.  The $x$ you've written in your question is the amount by which the translation operator is shifting your wavefunctions, which is a different thing entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The momentum operator can only be replaced by the derivative when you’re talking about matrix elements in position space basis, otherwise it is just an abstract operator which acts on states.